# Android bi-directional sqlite database synchronization

Tags: android, database, sqlite, synchronization

I've done a lot of search about this but I don't found anything really useful.
I just want to know if it is possible to sync a remote database with an android sqlite database using SyncAdapter and content providers.
I don't want to use another solution like webservices or sending the database file to server, and if possible I need to implement rules to resolve conflicts.
Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008015/android-sqlite-bidirectional-synchronization-sqlite

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll still have to use something like web services to wire them together, there is no automatic mechanism to do that like sql replication or anything.  All the SyncAdapter provides is a system managed periodically run service that's intended to be used for syncing data.  You have to write all the code to talk to the local database and the remote database and manage moving the data between them.

Comment: I was just looking for an affirmation to the fact. +1