# Sync in Android sqlite and sql server (crud operation) in two ways

Tags: java, android, sql-server, asynchronous, synchronization

I am developing an android application which have

- sq lite db on my device
- server sql db on main server which sync them, with two identical
  (same fields structure and fields name)
- i need to develop synchronization between these db in 2 ways
- If I change database data in Android then It will change data on web server
- when i change data from sever then it should change data in android
- sync will run in 1 day automatically

  now the question is How do I sync those databases in Android?
  as i am newly entered in mobile world and i am internee also and they give said if i will done this work then i will be permanent.

found several things but i am at beginners level.
i don't find any samples. i have found similar questions here but does not find any code , any sample which only sync data on 2 way.

i will appreciate if some one will give me (open source project) or some sample code with some explanation.

or something like that which will show me a way to do this.

[How to sync SQLite database on Android phone with MySQL database on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511402/how-to-sync-sqlite-database-on-android-phone-with-mysql-database-on-server)

[Android bi-directional sqlite database synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500649/android-bi-directional-sqlite-database-synchronization?rq=1)

i have found these article but does not help me.

Comment: consider this situation, changes occured in both the databases, then what will happen? any 1 of the change will be discarded and overidden by the other change.

Comment: @DixitPatel what is this?

Comment: changes at the same time?

Comment: @Raj changes at the same time?

Comment: within a day, because you told that you want to sync the database once in a day.

Comment: @Raj leave the day point...... i want to start this . day time hour we will see them later but first where i should get started? need the startup point....

Comment: i recommend you to update the server database instantly and sync your android database once in a day that would be a better choice. i'll post you sample code for updating android db from server db.

Comment: @Raj thanks for ur copration. i really appritiate you

Comment: @Raj what shpold i hv to do... when i want to sync two way?

Comment: @Raj and how can i update my server db? can u provide some sample to do that.

Comment: you may instantly update the server db and update your android db when you wish, or vice versa.

Comment: the code i already provided will update your android db from server db.

Comment: this code will sync in 2 way? update both db's?

Comment: you have to write your own code for updating instant updates on server db

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23190/discussion-between-mak-and-raj)

Comment: @Raj can i have ur skype id ? so i can take help u by pm u!

Comment: @mak  dear mak i've the same condition, each and every word of your post applies to my situation. could you please guide me how did you achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 5):

Use this as your android service

```
public class Connector {

HttpClient httpClient = null;
HttpPost httpPost = null;
HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
String serverResponse = null;

public String callService(String url){

    try{
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        //Log.e("URL Response", serverResponse);
        serverResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e("Exception in connectivity", ex.toString());
    }
    //Log.e("URL Response", serverResponse);
    return serverResponse;
}

}
```

This class helps you updating android db

```
public class DbSync extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DB_PATH = "";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Your_Db_Name";
private SQLiteDatabase sqliteDb = null;
private String path = null;

public DbSync(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    path = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public void syncUsers(){
    try {
        String response = new TaskAsync().execute("URL_Where_Service_Running").get();
        Log.d("response", response);

        String tableName = "Table_Name";

        sqliteDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,  SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        sqliteDb.delete(tableName, null, null);

                    //here you have to parse your data from DB and insert using 
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("col_name1", parsedColumnValue);
        values.put("col_name2", parsedColumnValue);

        long status = sqliteDb.insert(tableName, " ", values);

        Log.d("database", Long.toString(status));


        sqliteDb.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You have to tailor the above code according to your data returned from DB.
hope it helps:)

Comment: This is awesome, but could you update your code for SDK 23+? 
Since `HttpClient` is supported for <= 22 SDK now days...