# Android Client/Server model

Tags: android, database, web-services, apache-axis, android-ksoap2

I have mobile application senior project called,"Traffics on Road to Atilim."
In this application, user can create or update  traffics event such as car accident, road under construction. Application will take GPS cordinates of user and insert event on google maps. Other user can see this event via google maps.

Problem is that android SQL lite is not based on server/client model and I think, I need that model for this application. Here is our application ER-diagram
[image]

My quistion is how can i implement client/server model in android application? I can or not?
If i can not implement do i have to sycn oracle database server via SQL lite ?

Comment: So your problem is that you don't know how to sync local Android DB with remote server DB ?

Comment: My first question is that is there a no way direct connection on oracle server with android application?If not, how to sync local android db with remote server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008015/android-sqlite-bidirectional-synchronization-sqlite

Comment: Easiest way would be to write an API for that (REST API).

Comment: I did research on this topic and what I read that there is no oracle api for android application for documented so i have to need sync right ?

Comment: For my project i wrote my own API. Android sends XML to my Server. Php parses it an updates the DB / returns results. Really depends on the scale of your project. My Db in this project gets 260hits/hour on average

Comment: I have been researching this subject for four days. I asked my teacher aswell, as result sync is not way for me. I need delpes method. Delpes can you clearly explain your idea? How can i write api ? have not any yet :S how can i setup net web service? what do i need for that ? is there a tutorial for writing net web service api and i need java net web service with servlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my question because of people who face with android database connection.
I have been researching this subject for 6 days and i have find best way is that usingweb service. I chosee web service with JAVA axis2.

[Here is a link that show how to implement web service](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zn8vLBOEhic)

[here android android web service client tutorial](http://jatin4rise.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/webservicecallfromandroid/)

I succesfully did android web service client with java implemented web service using this tutorials. But i need MS database 2008 implements now if anyone know i will appriciate that. Thanks