# Android - online offline synchronization of large SQLite database

Tags: android, synchronization, android-sqlite

I am developing an Android application to collect the store (Grocery) information.
The application have modules to create store, set it's attributes like address, lat lng, operating hours, manager details, building photos, etc.
Once the store is created user need to list down the assests of that store by clicking photos and providing it's details.

To store all this details, i have around 15 SQLite tables.

Now i want to implement feature of 'Synchronization', all this captured details need to send to server whenever connection is available otherwise detail should be stored locally and whenever connection is available it should move to server.

Also, please note that the number of tables may increase up to 40 as application grows.

I searched for the solutions/approaches for this on Google but in most of the article or example they have mentioned for small scale application having small data.

I have also implemented synchronization feature for small datatable (2 tables), where i checked for last updated timestamp on server and local and if it's different then we synchronize the data. I don't this i should use this approach for such large scale and large database.

I have one approach which doesn't depend on numbe of tables.
I am planning to have single table which store the following data

id
URL
request header
request body

Now let's say connection isn't available while sending request so it will be stored in table. Whenever connection is available it start reading the table and execute the request, on success it will remove the entry from table. With this approach we need only one table in SQLite.

The problem with this approach is when we want to retrieve data offline how we can do that? Do we need to have local database schema same as server?

Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008015/android-sqlite-bidirectional-synchronization-sqlite

Answer (score 0):

If you are syncing data with a server and you are removing local storage data ,which is incorrect as per my knowledge ,in this case your app does not work offline.So for that when you sync data to a server at that time maintain some flag which data is synced.And then next time just check flag status if it's synced then do not synced data otherwise do syncing.
I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: You are syncing your data in a background  using asyncTask right? in this case no. of tables does not matter

Comment: I have already 15 tables and it may be increase up to 40, So data volume is large and store in local it's difficult as well as maintain flag for each table records  is difficult.

Comment: in that case store timestamp in shared preferences when syncing took place

Comment: Timestamps is common for all table or different for individual table?

Comment: only one timestamp for all tables

Comment: How can this possible with one timestamps?