# Sqlite database automatic synchronize across devices with log file

Tags: android, ios, database, sqlite, google-drive-api

In my case i have an application for `Android` and `iOS`, and i want to synchronize the `Sqlite` database across all devices that shares the same `Google Drive Account`.

Is there any way to create a `Log file` that whenever an entry ( from any table ) is `inserted`, `changed` or `deleted`, the database stores a log line into this file? 
And then download the Database file from Google Drive and synchronize with my Log File following the same steps?

I was looking for something that logs also the tables changes, inserts or drops.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008015/android-sqlite-bidirectional-synchronization-sqlite