# Bidirectional Data Synchronization between android sqlite and Derby

Tags: android, sqlite, synchronization, derby

We have build and Android app with sqlite db and a Windows program with JavaFX that can use either Derby db or sqlite db. Synchronization does not want to use a server yes old fashion wire form one device to another. So my question is has anyone found an open source API to accomplish this task? As a novice developer I might add that the perhaps the other fly in the soup is we would like to encrypt the data on both databases. This fly can be optional. The desktop development is using NetBeans and the Android development is the obvious Android Studio.
If anyone has a book or web site suggestion that would be great.
We can consider a NON FREE API with cost as a factor.

Comment: This is not quite an answer so I will just offer as a suggested web site. Also the API is not free though at one time this was open source      http://www.jumpmind.com/products/symmetricds/overview

Comment: check also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008015/android-sqlite-bidirectional-synchronization-sqlite